# Exclude bootstrap-vue icons with Webpack IgnorePlugin

Tags: vue.js, webpack, bootstrap-vue

Webpack bundle analyzer shows that icons from bootstrap-vue package are 535kb in size.

I don`t want to use them in a project, so I have been trying to exclude the package with a webpack IgnorePlugin.

According to example in [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/#using-filter-functions), I have tried to write this:

```
new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
        resourceRegExp: /^icons(.*)$/,
        contextRegExp: /^bootstrap-vue(.*)$/
    })
```

but it didn`t work. The only thing I was able to reproduce, is to completely exclude bootstrap-vue lib via this constriction `new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/bootstrap-vue/)`

So how I can exclude only icons?

Comment: What is your project setup and how are you including Bootstrap-Vue? Icons should be something you have to *explicitly* import, and isn't imported by default.

Comment: I import only necessary components like
```import { FormGroupPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'; ```
and then 
```Vue.use(FormGroupPlugin);```

Comment: Hmm.. If that's the case it shouldn't be imported. You sure you aren't importing `IconsPlugin` anywhere?

Comment: They are included in the default setup when you use the entire plugin. E.g. `Vue.use(BootstrapVue)`. Also investigating this. Will post the response here if I'll find a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the way to ignore the icons from `bootstrap-vue`:

```js
new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
  resourceRegExp: /\/icons\//,
  contextRegExp: /bootstrap-vue/,
});
```

Next time if you are in doubt try to use `checkResource` function instead, it's easier to write and understand in comparison to regexp:

```js
new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
   checkResource (resource, context) {
     if (context.includes('bootstrap-vue')) {
       console.log(resource, ':::', context)
       // check console to figure out how the resource is used
       // update the function until it's satisfies your case
       // then move to regexp if you wish
     }
     return false
   },
 })
```

---

But after doing this research it turned out that some components actually use some icons and icons in general are not as big as I expected. Using source of the `bootstrap-vue` had bigger impact on our bundle. So decided to stick with this approach instead